# Ruby how to use variables outside of included modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to split my code in RSpec into multiple files so it looks nicer. The current file looks like this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::MyController do
   let(:var1) {}
   let(:var2) {}
   it 'should calculate some value' do
      expect(var1 + var2).to eq('some value')
   end
end
```

Now this is how it looks after refactoring.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative './mycontroller/calculation'

RSpec.describe Api::MyController do
   let(:var1) {}
   let(:var2) {}
   include Api::MyController::Calculation
end
```

And this is how calculation.rb looks like.

```
module Api::MyController::Calculation
   it 'should calculate some value' do
      expect(var1 + var2).to eq('some value')
   end
end
```

The problem now is that when it runs, it complains var1 and var2 is not defined.

Comment: You should note that `let` is not a Ruby syntax thing - rather its a RSpec thing that uses metaprogramming to create memoized helpers. Thus you can't really understand how let works in different context by just looking at the language.  https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for RSpec's [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

```
# spec/support/shared_examples/a_calculator.rb
RSpec.shared_examples "a calculator" do
  it 'should calculate some value' do
    expect(x+y).to eq(result)
  end
end
```

You then include the shared example with  any of:

```
include_examples "name"      # include the examples in the current context
it_behaves_like "name"       # include the examples in a nested context
it_should_behave_like "name" # include the examples in a nested context
matching metadata            # include the examples in the current context
```

You can pass context to the shared example by passing a block:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/shared_examples/a_calculator'
RSpec.describe Api::MyController do
  it_should_behave_like "a calculator" do
    let(:x){ 1 }
    let(:y){ 2 } 
    let(:result){ 3 }  
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a bare module like you can for shared contexts.